# how to access Google Cloud VM console to enable ssh?

Tags: centos, google-cloud-platform

Hope all doing well.

we've a GCE Centos VM. The ssh was fine but disabled (stopped sshd service and chkconfig off) due to security reasons. We need to enable ssh now, is there a way to access the VM console to do this? or is there any other ways to enable ssh on Google cloud VM?

Comment: Is your issue resolved?If yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it?

Answer (score 1):

**To solve your issue** follow steps below:

1. Enable serial console connection by following documenation [Enabling access for a VM instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#enable_instance_access) with `gcloud` command:

   ```
   gcloud compute instances add-metadata NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE \
   --metadata serial-port-enable=TRUE
   ```

   or go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> click on `EDIT` -> go to section **`Remote access`** and check `Enable connecting to serial ports`
2. If you dont have user and password to login, shutdown your VM and set a startup script by adding at the section **`Custom metadata`** key `startup-script` and value:

   ```
   useradd --groups google_sudoers tempuser
   echo "tempuser:password" | chpasswd
   ```

   and then start your VM.
3. Connect to your VM via serial port by following documetation [Connecting to a serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole) with `gcloud` command:

   ```
   gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE
   ```

   or go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> and click on `Connect to serial console`
4. Enable SSH and start sshd:

   ```
   $ sudo chkconfig sshd on
   $ sudo systemctl start sshd
   ```
5. Disable access via serial port connection by following documenation [Disabling interactive serial console access](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#disable_access) with `gcloud` command:

   ```
   gcloud compute instances add-metadata NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE \
   --metadata serial-port-enable=FALSE
   ```

   or go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_VM_INSTANCE` -> click on `EDIT` -> go to section **`Remote access`** and uncheck `Enable connecting to serial ports`

Keep in ming that accordingly  to the documentation [Interacting with the serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console):

> **Caution**: The interactive serial console does not support IP-based access
>   restrictions such as IP whitelists. If you enable the interactive
>   serial console on an instance, clients can attempt to connect to that
>   instance from any IP address. Anybody can connect to that instance if
>   they know the correct SSH key, username, project ID, zone, and
>   instance name. Use firewall rules to control access to your network
>   and specific ports.

In addition, have a look at the 3rd party article [Resolving getting locked out of a Compute Engine](https://medium.com/google-cloud/resolving-getting-locked-out-of-a-compute-engine-85800251890b).